# Adding and saving an entry to an array dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i am having a UITableView with a list of items.if i add a new item,it is getting added to the list but if i move to other view and come back its just vanishing.i want it to be saved like that and also if we delete it,it should be removed permanently. i got the item list from a plist

```
NSString *fileForCategoryList = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kCATEGORY_LIST ofType:kP_List];
self.arrayForCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:fileForCategoryList];
```

And this is how i am editing the list.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView  editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
// No editing style if not editing or the index path is nil.
if (self.editing == NO || !indexPath) return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
// Determine the editing style based on whether the cell is a placeholder for adding content or already 
// existing content. Existing content can be deleted.    
if (self.editing && indexPath.row == ([self.arrayForCategories count])) 
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
} 
else 
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

// Update the data model according to edit actions delete or insert.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
    [self.arrayForCategories removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableViewC reloadData];
} 
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
{
    UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:kYOUR_TITLE message:kEMPTY delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:kOK, nil];
    self.myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
    [self.myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [myAlertView addSubview:self.myTextField];
    [myAlertView show];
    [myAlertView release];

}
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
if ([self.myTextField text])
    [self.arrayForCategories addObject:[self.myTextField text]];
    [self.tableViewC reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take an array in app delegate.And when you want to add any item ,add it to the app delegate's array.Use the same array for deletion also.

Comment: Can this help in adding items to the array dynamically??